# Cannot find module 'hbs', express-handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to use express-handlebars view engine for express and I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'hbs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at new View (C:\Users\WilPrim\Desktop\node-app\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:81:14)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\WilPrim\Desktop\node-app\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\WilPrim\Desktop\node-app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at C:\Users\WilPrim\Desktop\node-app\routes\routes.js:5:6
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\WilPrim\Desktop\node-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\WilPrim\Desktop\node-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
```

**Here is my Code:**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const hbs = require("express-handlebars");
const router = require("./routes/routes");

//set up express app
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view options', {layout: './layouts/layout'});

app.use(router);
```

Comment: Silly question, but have you run `npm install --save express-handlebars`?

Comment: Yes i have. Didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the command finished with an error, or that you can verify the package is installed in `node_modules` and listed as a dependency and the error persists?

Comment: I finished the command and it is installed but still getting that same error that it cannot find the module 'hbs'

Comment: Oh, just noticed the issue

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the `express-handlebars` [documentation](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars), you have to setup and register the view engine manually:

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();
var hbs = exphbs.create({ /* config */ });

// Register `hbs.engine` with the Express app.
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// ...still have a reference to `hbs`, on which methods like `loadPartials()`
// can be called.
```

Looking a little bit further down in the documentation, looks like you can still use the `.hbs` extension with a bit of configuration:

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();

app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

Comment: I had this same issue and using the second bit of code at the bottom, I resolved the issue. But now hbs is looking for a main.hbs file in the views folder

Comment: If you get the error from `monsterpiece` use the following `app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({extname: '.hbs', defaultLayout: false}))`

Comment: might need to set views path as well. `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));`

Answer (score 2):

use command -- `sudo npm link hbs`

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some explanation to your post. What does the command do, why should OP use it, how it solves the problem?

Comment: It should be the fastest way

Comment: Using `sudo` with `npm` can be a security problem. It gives any script in the package and its dependencies that are being installed root level access to the machine.

Answer (score 1):

you might have named the main folder as "express"
just change the name of folder,delete "package.json" and try
"npm install"  again and then 
"npm install express"
"npm install hbs"

Answer (score 1):

```
/* been using this format for some time now, never had problems */ 
// import system modules
const hbs = require('express-handlebars');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// configuring express-handlebars as hbs
app.engine('hbs', hbs.create({
    extname: 'hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'main'
}).engine)

// system(app) routes
app.get('/', (req, res, next)=>{
    res.render('home', {title: 'HBS TITLE'});
});

// system listening port
app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score -1):

install this module on terminal --> npm i hbs

Answer (score -3):

try npm install and npm audit fix multiple times then rum the server after ex

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).